# Given a root word, how can i get variations of it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I want all the variations of a word, given a root word. For example, given the word - **transfer**, I would like to get an array like this back - [transfering, transferred] etc. How do I do this in python? I feel it is like the opposite of stemming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [with NLTK, How can I generate different form of word, when a certain word is given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145020/with-nltk-how-can-i-generate-different-form-of-word-when-a-certain-word-is-giv)