# Missing some form of words not being generated with wordnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, wordnet

With reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45158719/11515590), I tried to sample the word "play"

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

forms = set() #We'll store the derivational forms in a set to eliminate duplicates
for happy_lemma in wn.lemmas("play"): #for each "happy" lemma in WordNet
    forms.add(happy_lemma.name()) #add the lemma itself
    for related_lemma in happy_lemma.derivationally_related_forms(): #for each related lemma
        forms.add(related_lemma.name()) #add the related lemma

print(forms)
```

And I got the following output:-

```
{'play', 'playing', 'playlet', 'player'}
```

Is there anyway to include words like 'played', 'plays' with the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet [does not have](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=plays) the word "plays", as it is the *inflected* form of either the noun or verb "play", not a derivation. You see "playing" in your output because it is an adjective (e.g., "playing field") derived from "play", not because it is the present participle form of "play".

[Here](http://languagetools.info/grammarpedia/derivinfl.htm#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20key%20distinctions,used%20to%20mark%20grammatical%20information.) are more information about inflection vs derivation:

> Derivational morphemes make fundamental changes to the meaning of the stem whereas inflectional morphemes are used to mark grammatical information.